# How to restrict edit action to only current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, devise

How can you make a user edit action only available if the user is current user? I am using devise.

Devise has this:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy], notice: 'you must sign in first!'
```

But all this does is make sure a user is logged in not if a user is equal to current user? I want to make sure other users aren't able to edit other users accounts.

What is the best way to do this? Should I create a new `before_filter`? I couldn't find any standard way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `current_user` method provided by `devise`. Here you can read more -[current_user method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers).

```
def edit
  unless current_user 
    redirect_to home_path, :alert => "Restricted area" 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I highly advise looking into the **CanCanCan** gem to handle these things. In such a case your code would look something like:

**View:**

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if can? :update, @user %>
    # Edit something 
    <%= link_to edit_profile_path(@user), class: 'user' do %>
      Edit your profile
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And in your Users controller or such you would add the following line which would take care of the case where a user manually types a url unto the browser:

**Controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   load_and_authorize_resource
   ...
```

More info and docs: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Comment: This doesn't prevent someone from typing the url manually it only prevents links from displaying. That is what I want to solve.

Comment: Actually it does. With CanCanCan you will put this on top of your users controller: "load_and_authorize_resource", and if they type a resource (i.e. their own profile) into the browser manually which isn't theirs, they will get redirected to a page of your choosing.

Comment: Please update your answer. Code in views and code in controller.